# Facebook Graph Places Search API not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook-graph-api, xmlhttprequest

I want to use the Facebook Graph Places Search API to extract pictures of places however i get an error 0f 400 bad request. I tried using the User Acess token and the App token but it still doesn't work

Here is the code

```
let input = document.getElementById("input");

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET","https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&q=" + input.value + "&fields=picture&limit=3&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")

xhr.onload = function () {
    if (this.status === 200) {
    let data = JSON.parse(responseText)
    console.log(data);      
    }
}

xhr.send();

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the API version you use this is most likely due to the picture field and you should see an error response like `(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (picture) on node type (PlaceInformation)`, either remove the picture field from the request or specify an API version (v3.2 at max) for that request.

Comment: But I am using the latest version v3.3 and I need the picture field because i want to fetch the picture of the place

Comment: @I_code then you will need to go via the `page` field of the `PlaceInformation` object first - but that will require Page Public Content Access

Comment: What is the Public Content Access? And how do I get. Does it require a user authentication?

Comment: Like I said, if you use v3.3 you need to remove the picture field because it's not supported anymore in v3.3. If you need the picture field you'd need to use v3.2 or any lower available version.

Comment: @lar.schwarz I don't think v3.2 or lower is available. I checked the graph explorer page and I only saw v.3.3

Comment: It's still avail, but it depends on when your app was created. v3.2 is available until April 30, 2021.